# Why can't I require files in gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins, rubygems, require

I am getting this error:

`correlation_id/lib/correlation_id/controller_extension.rb:1:in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant CorrelationId (NameError)`

The following is based on what is generated by the command `rails plugin new correlation_id`

In the `lib` folder:

**correlation_id.rb**

```
require 'correlation_id/controller_extension'

module CorrelationId
end
```

**correlation_id/controller_extension.rb**

```
module CorrelationId
  module ControllerExtension

    def self.included(klass)
      klass.class_eval do
        after_filter :pass_correlation_id
      end
    end

    def pass_correlation_id
      correlation_id = request.headers['Correlation-ID'] || SecureRandom.uuid
      headers['Correlation-ID'] = correlation_id
    end
  end
end


byebug

ApplicationController.send :include, CorrelationId::ControllerExtension
```

Now, let's for a moment forget the fact that for some reason I get an error because my gem doesn't know what `byebug`is or can't figure our what `ApplicationController` is. Why can't I require the second file in the first? I get the error as listed above!

All the cool kids manage to do this, but I can't! Check it out:

[Byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug/blob/master/lib/byebug.rb)

[Active_model_serializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/lib/active_model_serializers.rb)

[Figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro/blob/master/lib/figaro.rb)

Comment: It's probably to provide some base functionality as to keep the system DRY - and further, software development is somewhat incestuous; once one gem creator does something, others follow :)

Comment: I know why it is done. The question is a matter of why does it give me an error, but not them?

Comment: Ohhh - I didn't see the error. What's the message you've received?

Comment: Actually, for some reason, it works now. The only issue I have now is the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831530/how-to-keep-my-gem-self-contained-without-having-to-edit-any-core-source-rails

Comment: Let me have a looook!