# How to keep my gem self-contained without having to edit any core source Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins, rubygems

I want to add a filter to the `ApplicationController` but I want to do it within my gem.

What I want to avoid is the following:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include MyGem
end
```

I do not want that. I don't want to have to include my module in the source code.

I am having issues though.

Here is the relevant code:

**lib/correlation_id/controller_extension**

```
module CorrelationId
  module ControllerExtension

    def self.included(klass)
      klass.class_eval do
        after_filter :pass_correlation_id
      end
    end

    def pass_correlation_id
      correlation_id = request.headers['Correlation-ID'] || SecureRandom.uuid
      headers['Correlation-ID'] = correlation_id
    end
  end
end

ApplicationController.send :include, CorrelationId::ControllerExtension
```

**lib/correlation_id.rb**

```
require 'correlation_id/controller_extension'

module CorrelationId
end
```

Now, when I'm in the `test/dummy` directory, which is a test rails app for my gem, I try to boot up the server using `rails s` and I get the following error:

```
/correlation_id/lib/correlation_id/controller_extension.rb:17:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant ApplicationController (NameError)
```

I'm clearly having problems with referencing ApplicationController to monkey-patch it.

How would I manage this? I want my gem to be self-contained.

Comment: So you want your gem to do something without adding it to your controller code?

Comment: It will be added to the controller code. However, I want it added to the controller within the gem, not within the source code itself.

Comment: I don't think you can call code you don't reference but I'll leave this to someone more experienced than myself.

Comment: @jkeuhlen It isn't a matter of not referencing. It's that I'll be referencing it in my gem. The problem is I seem to have trouble referencing it in the gem.

Comment: But then where does your gem come into the code base? It has to be executed from somewhere?

Comment: Exactly. Apparently, from the gem I am able to target `ActionController::Base`, but when the gem loads, `ApplicationController` is not yet loaded.

Comment: He wants to add the code into the `ApplicationController` with the gem

Comment: @RichPeck precisely. Within the gem, I want to do `ApplicationController.send :includes, MyGemModule`. Something of that sort. The issue I'm currently having is that `ApplicationController` is not yet loaded.

Comment: Perhaps you'll want to something like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11348332/how-can-i-extend-applicationcontroller-in-a-gem), and the [referenced gist](https://gist.github.com/themusicman/3057139)

Comment: @RichPeck I just figured it out. Will answer this with details.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works. What I did was prematurely create `ApplicationController` with the appropriate inheritance. Note, many people use the `rails-api` gem, so I factored in them to ensure the fact that it would work.

Also, note: You must inherit from a class because otherwise `ApplicationController` will be a usual class that doesn't understand what `after_filter` is.

```
module CorrelationId
  module ControllerExtension

    def self.included(klass)
      klass.class_eval do
        after_filter :pass_correlation_id
      end
    end

    def pass_correlation_id
      correlation_id = request.headers['Correlation-ID'] || SecureRandom.uuid
      headers['Correlation-ID'] = correlation_id
    end

    def self.base_controller_inheritance
      if Gem::Specification.find_all_by_name('rails-api').any?
        ActionController::API
      else
        ActionController::Base
      end
    end
  end
end

class ApplicationController < CorrelationId::ControllerExtension.base_controller_inheritance
  include CorrelationId::ControllerExtension
end
```

I imagine there might be a better way to check if they are using `ActionController::API` and if so, please do share, but as of now, this seems like the most solid way to do it.